# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'An attempt has been made to add the same field more than once.' error in outlook vsto addin c#

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I have to add `Categories` column to current view. I have the following code in the ThissAddIn_Startup method.

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    outlookNameSpace = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    inbox = outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.
                    OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    items = inbox.Items;
    items.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", true);
    Outlook.TableView CurView = ((Outlook.TableView)inbox.CurrentView);
    var viewField = CurView.ViewFields.Add("Categories");
    var columnFormat = viewField.ColumnFormat;
    columnFormat.Align = Outlook.OlAlign.olAlignRight;
    columnFormat.Width = 10;
    CurView.Save();
    CurView.Apply();
}
```

After running this code I am not able to add `Categories` column to the view.
Anyone help me with this.

Comment: `var viewField = CurView.ViewFields.Add("Categories");` I am going to go out on a limb and suggest `Categories` may already be in `CurView.ViewFields`.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    outlookNameSpace = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    inbox = outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.
                    OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    items = inbox.Items;
    items.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", true);
    Outlook.TableView CurView = ((Outlook.TableView)inbox.CurrentView);
    var viewField = CurView.ViewFields["Categories"];
    var columnFormat = viewField.ColumnFormat;
    columnFormat.Align = Outlook.OlAlign.olAlignRight;
    columnFormat.Width = 10;
    CurView.Save();
    CurView.Apply();
}
```

If this works, I suggest you modify the code to check if the `Categories` field is present and add it if not... Alternatively you can remove all columns and add only the ones you need:

```
// remove all columns 

while (CurView.ViewFields.Count > 1) 
{ 
  CurView.ViewFields.Remove(1); 
} 

// re-add needed columns 
CurView.ViewFields.Add("Categories"); 
CurView.ViewFields.Add("ReceivedTime"); 
CurView.ViewFields.Add("Subject");
```

Comment: Worked but after adding Categories to ViewFields array all the other columns got removed and only categories, size columns are present.

Comment: sorry, my bad... I have edited the comment. Please check it

Comment: I'm confused... Where do you add `Categories`?

Comment: In my addin I'm trying to add a category to a mail. I have successfully added categories to mails. Now when opening my inbox after adding the `Categories` column I am getting a card with( some specified color). Now I want to add that `Categories` column through code. I have executed the code u have posted and I successfully got the card icon along with the color but only the `Categories` column is present in the columns grid. I need all the previous columns and a categories column in the Columns Grid.

Comment: my code does not add `Categories`, it just retrieve it from the view... that is why your code was failing to start with...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173832/discussion-between-roopteja-and-leonardo-seccia).

Answer (score -1):

You need to check whether a particular field is already presented in the current view. For example, try to run the following VBA macro in Outlook:

```
Sub DemoViewFieldsAdd() 
  Dim oTableView As Outlook.TableView    
  Dim oViewFields As Outlook.ViewFields 
  Dim oViewField As Outlook.ViewField 
  Dim oInbox As Outlook.folder 

  Set oInbox = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

  If oInbox.CurrentView.ViewType = olTableView Then 
    Set oTableView = oInbox.CurrentView 
    Set oViewField = oTableView.ViewFields("Categories") 
    If oViewField Is Nothing Then 
      Set oViewField = oTableView.ViewFields.Add("Categories") 
    End If 
  End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: Eugene I have written the same code and after running it Categories is not added to my currentView.

Comment: Try to check the resulting `XML` markup of the `View`. And then do manual changes in Outlook and check the `XML` code. So, you may compare them and figure out what is wrong.